# Method doesn't return controlling

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a grid on WPF form and another class, that has some events. From my wpf form i subscribe on those events and i want them to add some objects to my grid, but only that i have is "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it." How can I avoid this proble and get same functionality?

Comment: +1 for points so you can comment

Comment: This is a duplicate question: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146942/the-calling-thread-cannot-access-this-object-because-a-different-thread-owns-it) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996162/the-calling-thread-cannot-access-this-object-because-a-different-thread-owns-it) or about eight others :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been covered ad nauseam on StackOverflow and elsewhere. You need to use the Dispatcher to marshal your access back to the UI thread. For example:

```
private void OnSomeEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // this is being called on a thread other than the UI thread so marshal back to the UI thread
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((ThreadStart)delegate
    {
        // now the grid can be accessed
        grid.Whatever = foo;
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a cross-threading issue.  Look into delegate creation so you can safely invoke another thread to modify something that was created on the different thread.  Here is a good MSDN article about how to make these thread-safe calls.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)